# How to implement Abril-Fatface font-family in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, yarn-v2

Tried inserting the Abril-Fatface file in all the android and iOS config files and also used it in the customm theme of react-native-elements, but the components are not picking up the font.

Need to use the font in custom theme of react-native-elements

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.